# Pivot longer for comparing case and control samples instead of having NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame that looks similar to this

```
gene_id gene_short_name S1-Case S2-Case S3-Case S4-Control S5-Control S6-Control
EN0001  TFG             0.003   0.001   0.002   0.001       0.002     0.003
```

I would like to have

```
gene_id gene_short_name Case   Control
EN0001  TFG             0.003  0.001
EN0001  TFG             0.001  0.002
EN0001  TFG             0.002  0.003
```

The code I have tried is this

```
df_longer <- pivot_longer(df, cols  = -c(gene_id, gene_short_name), names_to = c("sample", ".value"), 
         names_sep = "-", names_repair = "check_unique" )
```

but this gives me

```
   gene_id gene_short_name  Sample Case   Control
EN0001     TFG              S1      0.003  NA
EN0001     TFG              S2      0.001  NA
EN0001     TFG              S3      0.002  NA
EN0001     TFG              S4      NA     0.001
EN0001     TFG              S5      NA     0.002
EN0001     TFG              S6      NA     0.003
```

Is there a way to remove these in pivot_longer or would I have to rearrange my data before using pivot longer?
Thank you

Comment: To confirm, the `S[1-6]` is not meaningful?

Comment: This is error prone, you should rename the controls to match the associated cases!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are discarding the leading `S[0-9]-` portion, let's use `names_pattern=` instead and discard the leading portion.

```r
pivot_longer(df, cols  = -c(gene_id, gene_short_name),
    names_to = ".value", names_pattern = ".*-(.*)")
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   gene_id gene_short_name  Case Control
#   <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 EN0001  TFG             0.003   0.001
# 2 EN0001  TFG             0.001   0.002
# 3 EN0001  TFG             0.002   0.003
```

*Edit*: to keep the `S[1-6]`, this works here and might be good enough to work in general. I've kept the helper variables `rn1` and `rn2` mostly to show what they contain, they can safely be removed after the second `pivot`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(rn1 = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols  = -c(rn1, gene_id, gene_short_name)) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("S", "var")) %>%
  group_by(rn1, var) %>%
  mutate(rn2 = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(c(gene_id, gene_short_name, rn1, rn2), names_from = var, values_from = c(value, S))
# # A tibble: 3 × 8
#   gene_id gene_short_name   rn1   rn2 value_Case value_Control S_Case S_Control
#   <chr>   <chr>           <int> <int>      <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
# 1 EN0001  TFG                 1     1      0.003         0.001 S1     S4       
# 2 EN0001  TFG                 1     2      0.001         0.002 S2     S5       
# 3 EN0001  TFG                 1     3      0.002         0.003 S3     S6
```

---

Data

```
df <- structure(list(gene_id = "EN0001", gene_short_name = "TFG", "S1-Case" = 0.003, "S2-Case" = 0.001, "S3-Case" = 0.002, "S4-Control" = 0.001, "S5-Control" = 0.002, "S6-Control" = 0.003), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to keep my sample numbers as well in a separate column? just as S1, S2 and so on

Comment: Yes, possible, though not trivial. I don't know how generally this will apply, so caveat emptor. Let me know if it works on the full dataset! @Sabrina

Comment: Thank you, it did work on the full dataset

Answer (score 0):

Not the efficient code but an alternate approach

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with('S'))) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('s','c'), sep = '-') %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(gene_id,gene_short_name), names_from = c, values_from = value, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(c(Case, Control))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  gene_id gene_short_name  Case Control
  <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
1 EN0001  TFG             0.003   0.001
2 EN0001  TFG             0.001   0.002
3 EN0001  TFG             0.002   0.003
```